# Posix Pthread in C

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I have the following questions regarding pthread of posix.

- When we receive data in `pthread_join()` returned by the function being executed by a thread, we type cast the variable like `(void **)` even though the variable is a single pointer.

  ```
  int *x;

  pthread_join(tid,(void**)&x);

  printf("%d",*x);
  ```
- Should I derefrence the type casted argument (in case of structure)? Why can't I do like
  `struct Data *obj= & (struct Data*)arg;`?

  ```
  int main()
  {
   ...
   pthread_create(tid,NULL,Foo,&obj);
   ...
  }
  void *Foo(void *arg)
  {
      struct Data *obj=* (struct Data*)arg;
  }
  ```
- How does `pthread_join()` internally receives the returned variable.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you should never do `(void**)&x` as pointers off different types need not be of the same size.

Now, some scenarios (some valid, some working but invalid and some just broken):

Foo() returning a pointer to an `int (valid)`:

```
void* Foo(void *arg)
{
    int *ret = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ret = 42;
    return ret;
}

void *ptr;
int *x;
pthread_join(thread, &ptr);
x = ptr;
printf("%d", *x);
free(x);
```

Foo() returning an int (invalid but usually work):
Platforms where int is larger than a pointer this will not work.

```
void* Foo(void *arg)
{
   return 42;
}

void *ptr;
int x;
pthread_join(thread, &ptr);
printf("%d", (int)ptr);
```

Foo() returning a pointer to static int (invalid and never works):
All static memory in Foo() is freed when Foo() returns, before `pthread_join()` can copy the value.

```
void* Foo(void *arg)
{
   int ret = 42;
   return &ret;
}

void *ptr;
int *x;
pthread_join(thread, &ptr);
x = ptr;
printf("%d", *x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that: at your level of understanding of C casts should be simply forbidden.
If you learned that in a course, this is not really high quality.

First of all, `&x` is the address of a pointer so the result is `int**`, so well two indirections.

But casting that `int` away is dangerous, pointers to `int` and `void` don't have necessarily the same width on different platforms. So please do

```
void*x;
pthread_join(tid, &x);

printf("%d",*(int*)x);
```

Comment: But doesn't pthread_join takes a double pointer void variable? Or passing a single pointer void variable is valid

Comment: Since when is the width of a pointer-to-void and pointer-to-anything-else platform-dependent and *not* defined by the standard? Is there a standard-compliant platform where `sizeof(<type>*)` and `sizeof(void*)` are exceptional in the case where <type> happens to be a pointer-to-int (or any other pointer type as far as that goes)? Or did you intend to reflect an alignment issue instead?

Comment: size(void*) >= sizeof(<type>*) is what the standard says as far as I remember. But you will probably have to look in a museum for any platform using different sizes for different pointer types.

Comment: @Alfred, I am not sure that I understand your question. if `x` is a `void*` then `&x` is a `void**`.

Comment: @JoelKlinghed, I don't think that the standard foresees any kind of relation between the sizes. The only thing it enforces is that `sizeof(void*)` and `sizeof(char*)` (etc) are the same, and even that their representation be the same. On architectures with segmented memory pointers can be realized differently for different base types.